# navbar wont shrink when in dev tools with responsive design

Tags: media

im having trouble with media query's and responsive designs

I cant seem to get the bottom nav to shrink when page gets smaller it just goes off page what am i doing wrong can someone please help me correct my code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@500&display=swap');

*{  margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'DM Sans', sans-serif;
    ;
}

.header-top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background:#A4E0EB;
    padding: 0 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
  }

.header-top .header-top-container
{display: flex; align-items: center;
 }


.header-top .header-top-container .header-top-quickSearch input[type="text"]
{border:1px solid#A4E0EB;
padding: 5px 10px;
outline: none;
border-radius: 4px;}

.header-top .header-top-container .header-top-quickSearch input[type="text"]:focus
{width: 250px}

.header-top .header-top-container ul{display: flex;
margin-right: 5rem;}



.header-top .header-top-container ul li{margin:0 12px;
font-size: 14px;
}

.header-top ul li a{color: #fff;}
.header-top ul li a:hover{color:#FFB5C3;}

 
/* header container */
.header-container { display: flex;
background-color:#f6f8f5;
font-family:'DM Sans', sans-serif;}
  
.header-container1{display: flex;
position: relative;}   

img.header-logo{right: 60em; bottom:-5em;
  position: absolute;}

  /* header container end */
  
  /* Links inside the navbar */
  .header-container a {
    float:left;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #6F7378;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 5;}

 
  /* The dropdown container */
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5;}
  
  /* Dropdown button */
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #6F7378;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
    margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
    z-index: 5;}

    .dropdown-content-grid{display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, max-content);}
      
      
      .blank{text-decoration: none;
          cursor:default;
          pointer-events: none;
      }

/* a tag & buttons underline */
*,
*:before
*:after {padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}

button{position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:'DM Sans', sans-serif;
color: #6F7378;
font-size: 1px;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
padding:0 10px;}




button:after{content: "";
position: absolute;
background-color: #FFB5C3;
height: 3px;
width: 0%;
left: 0;
bottom: -0.4px;}

button:hover:after{width: 100%;}

.home{position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:'DM Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #6F7378;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    padding:0 10px;}
    
    
    
    
.home:after{content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFB5C3;
    height: 3px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -0.4px;}
    
.home:hover:after{width: 100%;}

.header-container > .home:focus, .home:hover {color: #FFB5C3;}
.dropdown > button:focus, button:hover {color: #FFB5C3;}


/* a tag & buttons underline end */


  
  /* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */
  /* .navbar a.home:hover,.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #FFB5C3;
  } */
  
  /* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 5;

  }
  .dropdown button:focus + .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-content:hover {
    display: block;}
  
  /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: #6F7378;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 5;

  }

  .navPages a:hover{  color: #FFB5C3;}
  .navPages button:hover{color: #FFB5C3;}
  
  /* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
  /* .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color:#FFB5C3;
  } */

  
  /* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
  .dropdown .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    z-index: 5;

  }


.navPages{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;    
  z-index: 5;}

.header-container{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}



/* .toggle-button{position: absolute;
top: 0.75rem;
right: 1rem;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 30px;
height: 20px;}

.toggle-button .bar{height: 3px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFB5C3;
border-radius: 10px;} */

.wholebodycontainer{margin-top: 3rem;}

h1{display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
margin-bottom: 3rem;
font-size:35px;
letter-spacing: 0.75rem;
color: #506671;}

  /* Image Slider */
  
  *{Margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;}
    
    .swiper{width: 65%;
    height: fit-content;
  border-radius: 5px;}
    
    .swiper-slide img {width: 100%;}
    
    .swiper .swiper-button-prev, .swiper .swiper-button-next {color: #FFB5C3;}
    
    .swiper .swiper-pagination-bullet-active{background: #FFB5C3;}

     /* Image Slider End */

@media screen and (max-width:1340px) {}
```

^^^CSS^^^

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-uk">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cake & a'Cuppa Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Cake-and-Cuppa-Website-Up-To-Date-Style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
   
    <div class="body-wrapper">
      
      <header class="header" role="banner">
     

            <div class="header-top">
              <div class="header-top-container">
                      
                  <div class="header-top-quickSearch">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Search the store">
                  </div>
                        <ul class="header-top-menu">
                            <li class="header-top-menu-item"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                            <li class="header-top-menu-item"><a href="#">DELIVERY SERVICE</a></li>
                            <li class="header-top-menu-item"><a href="#">TEL:01904 690283</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                        
                        
              </div>
                </div>
        
         <div class="header-container">              
                 
         <header class="header">
            <div class="navPages-container">
                                <div class="header-container1"><img class="header-logo"-image src="c:\Users\micha\Desktop\cake-svg.png" alt="" width="155px" height="155px"></div>

                <nav class="navPages">
                  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                  </a>

                   <a class="home" href="#home">HOME</a>
                  
                            <div class="dropdown">
                          <button class="dropbtn">CELEBRATION CAKES
                            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                          </button>
                          <div class="dropdown-content">
                            <div class="dropdown-content-grid">
                            <a href="#">BIRTHDAY CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">OCCASION CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">SEASONAL CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">TODDLER CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">CAKES FOR HIM</a>
                            <a href="#">ANNIVERSARY CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">THANKSGIVING CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">NUMBER CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">CAKES FOR HER</a>
                            <a href="#">WEDDING CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">CHRISTMAS</a>
                            <a href="#">PRINCESS CaKES</a>
                            <a href="#">TODDLER CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">CHRISTENING CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">BURNS NIGHT GIFTS</a>
                            <a href="#">ROMANTIC CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">GIRLS BIRTHDAY CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">NEW BABY CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">VALENTINE'S DAY</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">BOYS BIRTHDAY CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">RETIREMENT CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">ST DAVID'S DAY CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">TEEN BIRTHDAY CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">GRADUATION CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">ST PATRICK'S DAY CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">NUMBER CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">RELIGIOUS CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">MOTHER'S DAY</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">CAKES WITH TOYS</a>
                            <a href="#">GET WELL SOON CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">EASTER</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">ANIMAL CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">GOOD LUCK CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">ST GEORGE'S DAY CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">HANDBAG & SHOE CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">WELL DONE CAKES</a>
                            <a href="#">EID CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">PRINCESS CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">FATHERS DAY CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">SUPERHERO CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">PRIDE DAY CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">SPORTING CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">HALLOWEEN CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">TECHNOLOGY CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">ROMANTIC CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">TWO~TIER CAKES</a>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <div></div>
                            <a href="#">RUDE BIRTHDAY CAKES</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="dropbtn">GIFT CAKES
                          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <a class="home" href="#home">PHOTOCAKES</a>
                      <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="dropbtn">CUPCAKES
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                      </button>
                      <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="home" href="#home">CAKES IN-A-TIN</a>
                    <div class="dropdown">
                      <button class="dropbtn">CORPORATE CAKES
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                      </button>
                      <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                
            </div>
         </div>
    
        </header>    
        


  <div class="wholebodycontainer">
<h1>YORKSHIRES FAVOURITE CAKE STORE</h1>

    <!-- image slider -->
    <div id="container-body">
        <div class="container">
    
          <div class="swiper">
    
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    
              <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="c:\Users\micha\Desktop\New Professional\tets\Untitled-3.png" alt=""></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="c:\Users\micha\Desktop\New Professional\tets\Untitled-3.png" alt=""></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="c:\Users\micha\Desktop\New Professional\tets\Untitled-3.png" alt=""></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="c:\Users\micha\Desktop\New Professional\tets\Untitled-3.png" alt=""></div>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    
          </div>
          </div>
    
          <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
          <script>
          const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
            autoplay:{delay: 5000,
            disableOnInteraction: false,},
    
            loop: true,
    
            pagination: {
              el: '.swiper-pagination',
              clickable: true,
            },
    
            navigation: {
              nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
              prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
    
          });
          </script>
    </div>
    <!-- image end -->
            </div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

^^^HTML^^^

I cant seem to get the bottom nav to shrink when page gets smaller it just goes off page what am i doing wrong can someone please help me correct my code